How to make an image of your Linux Install
I'm looking to physically replace my current linux boot hard drive with a new hard drive, but want to 'copy' the existing boot drive contents onto that new drive.
I assume the best way to do this is to create an image of the current one and then restore it onto the new drive.
I'd appreciate some details on doing this. In particular, I assume that the fstab will need to be edited for the new drive after restoring the image onto it.
Thanks!

Are you able to physically connect both disks at the same time? If not – then do you have a third disk with enough space to store the image?

Can you post actual /etc/fstab content ?

Yes, my plan was to actually have the old and the new one attached to the system at the same time before I physically removed the old. And then once it is clone to the new disk, boot from it -- Will it be a problem booting from the new clone if the old one is still physically attached to the system?

CloneZilla will do that very easily assuming new drive is equal or greater than old one, and both drives are concurrently attached to any system (doesn't matter which computer). Otherwise CloneZilla could do it too, but with a little bit more knowledge due to cases.

You have probably 100 different options here. Creating a full disk image will give you a 1:1 copy, which is "best" in some ways but suboptimal in others. (For example, a 'full' image is easier but slower to create and slower to write than specialized 'used space only' images. If the target disk is larger, both kinds of images will require additional steps to make use of the newly available disk space, compared to file-based copy methods.)
If you do want to use a full 1:1 image, it will be easiest to write it directly to the target disk – i.e. directly "restore" from disk A to disk B without creating an image file as such (because otherwise you'd need to store that image somewhere). This could be done just by copying data from /dev/sdx to /dev/sdy using generic tools like dd or pv or even cp. (I like ddrescue for its resume capability.)
Make sure to do this from some kind of 'live USB' system – it's not a good idea to image a filesystem that is actively being used by the OS.
It would be faster to clone the partition table first, then use filesystem-specific tools to clone each partition – tools like partclone are able to skip over "unused" areas based on filesystem metadata. This is exactly what CloneZilla does, and I'd suggest just using that.

Manual method:
sfdisk --dump /dev/sdx | sfdisk /dev/sdy
cp /dev/sdx1 /dev/sdy1                   # 1:1 copy a small partition
ntfsclone /dev/sdx2 -O /dev/sdy2         # efficiently copy a large partition
partclone.xxx -s /dev/sdx3 -O /dev/sdy3  # same for non-NTFS filesystems



Generally fstab does not use any drive-specific references. In most distributions it references either the partition-table UUID or the filesystem UUID, both of which are part of the 'data' and are copied through disk imaging. (Importantly, this means that if both disks are connected, there is no guarantee as to which one will be detected by the boot process – or later by fstab – as they both would have identical UUIDs everywhere.)
All of these methods expect the target disk to be of the same size or larger, and if it is larger, manual moving/resizing of partitions will be needed afterwards. A file-based copy would avoid that, although it will then usually require updating your fstab and your bootloader configuration; it also gives you the chance to migrate to a different filesystem.

Changing the type of the disk (e.g. SATA to NVMe) will require rebuilding the initramfs (initrd) image, as it includes the base drivers needed for Linux to access its own root filesystem, and most Linux distributions only build a very minimal initramfs that has only drivers necessary at that moment.
Similarly, if you use GRUB, it does something similar by embedding "modules needed to access /boot" into its core image, and will need to be re-grub-install'd and all that.
